# MonoDevelop: "A platform service implementation has not been found" error

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I took MonoDevelop 4.0.12 binaries from Debian's package archives (because could not find windows builds) and tried to run them under windows with this command (under windows):
"Mono-2.11.4\bin\Mono.exe" "monodevelop4.0.12\bin\MonoDevelop.exe"

it runs and works correctly for editing but when pressing F5 it fails to run the project being edited with this error:
"A platform service implementation has not been found"
(this same project compiles and runs with Mono from command line)

what is "platform service" and where can I find it for windows?
alternatively where can I find binaries of older versions of MonoDevelop?

I know about SharpDevelop but it cannot run on Mono (want to run same binaries of MonoDevelop on windows and linux with wine)

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b Please waste no more time on that dead project.

Comment: @LexLi my goal is to run same dev environment (not just similar but exactly same) on windows and linux (with Wine if necessary) and I have no need for anything newer than .NET 2.0 APIs (no need for WinForms/Asp.Net either) - hence old version of MonoDevelop. SharpDevelop would be a perfect fit if it could run without proprietary .NET framework

Comment: You have to explain first why VSCode + .NET 6 cannot meet your goal, as both are well supported by Microsoft. All others you mentioned are either dead, or not supported by Microsoft, or limited on Windows.

Comment: because it should run on windows XP. does not matter if it is "current" or "supported" or 20 years old, only if it works

Comment: It's rather interesting to see someone talking about Windows XP in 2022. I won't comment any more as I am not interested.

Comment: some factories prefer tried-and-true over new